# Writing a sequence-maybe monad using clojure.algo.monads

Tags: clojure, monads

I need help with writing a 'sequence-maybe-m' (a monad that combines the behaviour of a sequence monad with a maybe monad).

The rule should be:

- If any of the inputs are nil, then the whole expression fails.
- Otherwise, evaluate the body like a sequence monad would do.

```
    (domonad sequence-maybe-m [a [1 2 3] b [1 2 3]] (+ a b)) 
        ;; => (2 3 4 3 4 5 4 5 6)

    (domonad sequence-maybe-m [a [1 2 3] b nil] (+ a b)) 
        ;; => nil

    (domonad sequence-maybe-m [a [1 2 3] b (range a)] (+ a b)) 
        ;; => (1 2 3 3 4 5) same as 'for'

    (domonad sequence-maybe-m [a [1 2 3] b [1 nil 3]] (+ a b)) 
        ;; => nil
```

It'll be a bonus if it is compatible with the clojure.algo.monads library:

```
(defmonad sequence-maybe-m
     [m-result <...>
      m-bind   <...>
      m-zero   <...>
      m-plus   <...>
      ])
```

where <...> are functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
; helper function for nil-ness
(defn nil-or-has-nil? [xs] (or (nil? xs) (some nil? xs)))

; the actual monad
(defmonad sequence-maybe-m
          [m-result (fn [v] [v]) ; lift any value into a sequence

           m-bind (fn [mv f] ; given a monadic value and a function
                    (if (nil-or-has-nil? mv) ; if any nil,
                      nil ; result in nil
                      (let [result (map f mv)] ; map over valid input seq
                        (if (some nil? result) ; if any nils result
                          nil ; return nil
                          (apply concat result))))) ; else flatten resulting seq

           m-plus (fn [& mvs] ; given a sequence of mvs
                    (if (some nil-or-has-nil? mvs) ; if any nil,
                      nil ; result in nil
                      (apply concat mvs))) ; otherwise, join seqs

           m-zero []]) ; empty seq is identity for concatenation
```

The only point really worth watching out for here is the second `nil-or-has-nil?` in the `m-bind`. The first is expected - passed a monadic value, `m-bind` has to determine whether it's `nil`-ish and should immediately result in `nil`. The second checks the results of the computation - if it failed (producing any `nil`), then the overall result must be `nil` (as opposed to, say, the empty list resulting from `(apply concat [nil nil ...])`).

Answer (score 3):

The output of `domonad` must be a monadic value, in the case of `sequence-m` that means it must be a sequence. Asking for an output of `nil` breaks that and you do not have a monad.

What you are probably looking for is adding "maybe" to the sequence-monad directly using monadic transformers, quite easy to do and described here: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/1.2.0/clojure.contrib.monads/maybe-t.

You will want to write

```
(def sequence-maybe-m (maybe-t sequence-m))
```

where `maybe-t` adds the "maybe" to the sequence monad. Using this will make

```
(domonad sequence-maybe-m [a [1 2 3] b [1 nil 3]] (+ a b))
```

yield

```
(2 nil 4 3 nil 5 4 nil 6)
```

which is valid output for a monad of this type. If you need to cancel out results that have `nil` in them, just use `some nil?` on the output of the monad to check them.

Binding `nil` to `b` as you ask for in your example

```
(domonad sequence-maybe-m [a [1 2 3] b nil] (+ a b))
```

does not make sense either, since `nil` is not a sequence. In the transformed monad, the return value would be the empty list `()`. It would be more appropriate to bind `[nil]` to `b`, then you would get `(nil nil nil)`.

It helps to remember that monads are used to compose functions of the same signature and can themselves be part of such a composition, so they must yield monadic values (in this case, sequences) themselves and in their body any binding must also be with a monadic value.